# Binding data from a complex model to listview itemsource in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have this viewmodel which fetches data for me. This works fine.
 All i need is data in objProdList and I need to bind this to a listview.

```
     public class ProductDetailsViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            public IDataService DataService { get; private set; }
            public CustomerProductList objProdList { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; }

            public ProductDetailsViewModel(CustomerSelectContainer custrecord)
            {
                //Pull the product list data by customer
                //CustomerRecord = custrecord;
                DataService = ServiceRepository.GetService<IDataService>();
                objProdList =  DataService.GetCustomerProductList(custrecord.Customer);
                Title = "Product Details";
            }

        }
```

Here is the model for the customerProductList
I only need the CustomerProducts data on the listview

```
    public class CustomerProductList
    {
        [BsonId]
        public long CustomerProductListId { get; set; }

        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public List<CustomerProduct> CustomerProducts { get; set; } = new List<CustomerProduct>();

        public CustomerProductList()
        {
        }

        public CustomerProductList(Customer customer)
        {
            Customer = customer;
        }
    }
```

Here is what the customerproduct model look like.

```
    public class CustomerProduct
    {
        public string CustomerProductKey { get; set; }
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public Price Price { get; set; }
        public int RentalQuantity { get; set; }
        public int CircInventory { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryFrequency { get; set; }
        public decimal MinimumUsePercentage { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I bind objProdList.CustomerProduct to my listview itemsource in my xaml

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding objProductList.CustomerProducts}"

Comment: I tried that and it did not work

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71593/how-do-i-use-xaml-to-bind-to-a-property-inside-a-class-instance-in-the-view-model

Comment: I saw that example. Thats a very simple one. My model is complex

Comment: a list of objects is hardly complex.  Do you have the binding context set?  Is your model populated with data before the binding is applied?  Have you tried setting the ItemsSource in code *after* the data has loaded?

Comment: Yes I did that  BindingContext =  new ProductDetailsViewModel(data);. Model is populated with data after the binding. I can try itemsource in code and see what happens

Comment: if the binding happens before the data is assigned and you're not using INPC then the UI won't be notified when the data is ready.